# Do I roll sushi with or without gloves?

Tags: food-safety, equipment, sushi

So I was rolling sushi the other day and I noticed how much easier it is to do with out plastic gloves on.  The stickiness of the rice dose not accumulate all over your hands as fast as it does when you are wearing gloves making it much easier and faster.

The conundrum here is.. If I don't wear gloves I can make sushi much faster, keeping customers happy but according to the sanitation department, restaurant employee's must wear gloves if the food they are touching is no longer going to be cooked any further.

What do I do?

Comment: I would recommend following the rules of the sanitation department, if you work in the food industry. There is a reason the rules are there.

Comment: oh yea, of course, but there has to be a better way, I know the water trick with the knife and your hands if it is my sushi, but... time is money.

Comment: And sanitation rules are sanitation rules. Even if they appear pointless (not that I'm implying this here).

Answer (score 4):

As the comments already cover, thou shalt not trifle with the sanitation department rules if you want to **stay** in the business.

You might try tighter gloves or gloves of different (but still acceptable to the sanitation department) plastics/rubbers, or with different surface textures. Many "food service gloves" seem to the purchased on the *one size fits none* plan. Wiping your gloved hands frequently with a clean damp cloth may help, or rinsing them frequently under the sink.

Comment: I haven't rolled sushi professionally, but in the classes that I've taken the damp-towel trick was the recommended best means of avoiding sticking.